# Azure Function v2 file system write no longer works and throws 4058 no such file or directory error

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

The following code used to work in Azure Function v2 but now it no longer works.  What changed? Why this error now?

Background context: My function is a blogTriggered function that takes in the pdf blob and converts all pages to an image.  Pdf2png and Azure-Storage only support working with local Files,not blobs, so you are forced to write the blob to a file first, temporarily. Then delete them when done.  This worked 2 years ago, but recent changes in v2 broke it. I know the input folder exists because I can see it when I view files in Azure Portal. I'm not sure if it is related to changes in Node with using __dirname or something else is blocking writing files now? Please help. Thanks!

```
let input = __dirname + "/input/" + fileName;
fs.writeFile(input, pdfBlob, (err) => {
if (err) {
  context.log(err);
} else {
  context.log("The document has been saved temporarily");
}
})


{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'D:\home\site\wwwroot\pdf2png\input\mydoc.pdf'] errno: -4058, code: 
'ENOENT', syscall: 'open', path: 
'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\pdf2png\\input\\mydoc.pdf' }
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears v2 changed to be more strict on write permissions.  I changed it to point to tmp, which is d:\home\data\ is an Azure Function. 
let input = "d:\home\data\" + fileName;

It has to do with deployment packaging flag is Application Settings WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE. It removed write permissions, which is a good thing. In the past when I tried tmp it did not work, so I was forced to write to wwwroot.

Unfortunately, something else changed that broke pdf2png and ghostscript, which was working.  Guess they block that now. ugh.

Anyway, using tmp fixed this issue.